# Easy non-rounded roots in Java?

Tags: java, math

I have a piece of code getting the roots of an integer. I would like these roots to be rounded to something like 2 or 3 DP.

But `Math.sqrt()` (and eqivs for other roots) gives an automatically rounded square root.

I have done a bit of reaseach, and can't find a simple way of getting this. I don't really want to have to switch to another way, got to a library or anything else, `Math.sqrt()` is a nice easy way, just rounds it. Can I do this?

Comment: Did you try it? `System.out.println(Math.sqrt(1.123d))` gives `1.0597169433391165`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"rounded" here doesn't mean "rounded to integer value"; from the API: "the result is the double value closest to the true mathematical square root of the argument value".

Comment: Oh. But when I do square root of 4, it gives "2.0".

Comment: @ACarter What value are you looking for?

Comment: @ACarter: It's a double. Read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: @ACarter I didn't say that. I'm just intrigued by what number you could be hoping to get as the square root of 4 besides 2.0. If you're looking for 2 or 2.000, yours is a question of formatting output.

Comment: @Patrick87 (don't think you offended me, you didn't, I'm just being stupid) No, it was the number, not the formatting.

Comment: @ACarter it intrigues me what number did you actually expect :P

Comment: @kaoD I was thinking it would be a 2 followed by a long length of random digits.

Comment: Well, that's where you are having trouble! The square root of 4 is 2, because 2 * 2 = 4.